# How to create a global 32/64bit hook for FlashWindowEx?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

The goal is to prevent taskbar icons from ever flashing. Apparently Windows has no option to disable flashing, so I'm hoping to write a small program that would intercept all the calls to FlashWindow / FlashWindowEx from *any* application and simply discard them.

Can this be done? If so, could you give any hints/examples how to hook calls to FlashWindowEx (globally) that would work with both 32bit and 64bit apps and also with both regular API calls and DLL calls through GetProcAddress (Skype uses that).

Comment: Look into Microsoft's Detours library. I thought there was an option for it somewhere at least, though.

Comment: From what I've gathered, detours supports only 32 bit apps in its free version.

Comment: What about [this](http://i.imgur.com/ElsihIw.png)? Control panel > Ease of Access Centre > Use text or visual alternatives for sounds

Comment: [These are my settings](http://i.imgur.com/4LzY8zG.png), but unfortunately the taskbar still flashes. (edit: tried all the other combinations and checkboxes with no effect whatsoever)

Comment: Note that FlashWindowEx is not the only reason a window can flash on the taskbar. You would be better off suppressing the HSHELL_FLASH notification.

Comment: @RaymondChen Is HSHELL_FLASH a "lower level" device (used by FlashWindowEx) or are they 2 separate things that I need to take care of?

Comment: All flash requests regardless of source become HSHELL_FLASH.

Comment: @RaymondChen Great, that makes things a lot easier. So how can I suppress HSHELL_FLASH?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @blade I know I'm a bit late, but have you figured out a solution? It's 2021 and Microsoft still hasn't fixed their autohiding taskbar..

Comment: @CiriousJoker yep, it required injecting a DLL into every process. It wasn't as easy as I had hoped, but I got it working and here's the full project: https://github.com/bladeSk/StayFocused

Comment: @blade Amazing! I tried with RegisterShellHookWindow() & SetWindowsHookEx(). I could read SHELL_FLASH message, but not modify or prevent it. This tool works great, the only downside is that it doesn't automatically apply the injection when a new process is created. Also a delayed autostart feature would be nice.

Comment: It watches for windows being created, so it should definitely inject the DLL in real time. You should see it in the log. If this doesn't happen, then you're either trying to hook a privileged process or there's a bug in the watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`RegisterShellHookWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989.aspx) to intercept and discard `HSHELL_FLASH` notifications.

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx doesn't appear to intercept HSHELL_FLASH, but RegisterShellHookWindow seems to be what I'm looking for. Any ideas where I could find an example of using it?