# How to get FLASHWINFO struct from window handle?

Tags: c#, winapi

How to get FLASHWINFO struct from window handle in C#?

I have not found anything on this topic on StackOverflow.
Here's the article [Force window to blink when a particular event occurs in C# / WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8924556/3394380)

UPDATE: I want to check from one application if another application has a flashing window in it.

Comment: you need allocate and initialize it yourself, but not *get*

Comment: The code in the answer given in the link you posted in your question shows exactly how you do it. Frankly, open your eyes and look at the source code.

Comment: I want to check if windows flashing in another application.

Comment: @RbMm I need opposite task. See my previous comment.

Comment: @elgonzo I need opposite task. See my previous comment.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet there's no way to do this. The flashing state is temporary, so I doubt Windows stores the `FLASHWINFO` data anywhere except as needed during the animation itself. It almost certainly isn't queryable after it is applied via the `FlashWindowEx`.

Comment: Probably, the best you can do is to hook FlashWindowEx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695718/how-to-create-a-global-32-64bit-hook-for-flashwindowex

Comment: @MichaelGunter I'll try it and let you know results. Working with Windows hooks may be a hard task.

Comment: Hard and error-prone. Assuming for the moment that you can hook `FlashWindowEx`, you then have to calculate the exact amount of time the flash operation will take and then wipe out your program's state when that time has elapsed.

Comment: FWIW: I just used Resharper C++ to search a Windows program for usages of `FLASHWINFO` and `PFLASHWINFO`. The only place that this struct is used in the entire windows API is in the `FlashWindowEx` API. Therefore, there is no API that will return this info or fill in an existing structure with it (i.e. there is no way to query this info).

Comment: @MichaelGunter you should just post it as answer.

Comment: exist partial solution by `RegisterWindowMessageW(L"SHELLHOOK");` and then call [`RegisterShellHookWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989(v=vs.85).aspx) - we will receive this registered message with `HSHELL_FLASH` for this window handle (in *lParam*) when it begin flashed and with `HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED` when end flashed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. The flashing state is temporary, and windows won't store this information except internally, temporarily, as needed by the animation itself. I used Resharper C++ to search for usages of the `FLASHWINFO` struct and it's corresponding pointer type `PFLASHWINFO`. The only instance of this structure being used is in the `FlashWindowEx` method itself. There simply is no (public) API for querying this info.

You *may* be able to build something by hooking `FlashWindowEx`, but it's likely to be a little difficult to get right. Assuming for the moment that you *can* hook `FlashWindowEx`, you then have to calculate the exact amount of time the flash operation will take and then wipe out your program's state when that time has elapsed. If you'd like to try this approach, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695718/how-to-create-a-global-32-64bit-hook-for-flashwindowex).

Comment: _by hooking FindWindowEx_ ... typo?

Comment: Just a thought. I may be done by using DirectX to find out that particular portion of a screen is flashing.